# Global variable is needed in 2 windows

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have file called find.html and file result.html. both of them include this line in the head:

```
 <script src="func.js"></script>
```

in the file func.js , in the first line I wrote

```
var reciever_username;
```

Now, I have 2 function in the file "func.js"

```
function sendMessage(username){ //called from find.html
reciever_username = username;
alert(reciever_username); //work good
window.open('send_message.html', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250'); 

}

function message_handle(){//called from result.html
    alert(reciever_username); //show me : undefind
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since you didn't show *when/how* the functions are called, I can only assume that `message_handle` is called *before* `sendMessage` is called. Note though that each window/tab has their own context and variables are not shared between them. So if you load the two HTML files in two different windows/tabs, each has their own `reciever_username` variable.

Comment: You should use localStorage if you want to share data between windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is page window context, you have 2 different page context when you call a function with different window context it happens, you can try this instead:

```
function sendMessage(username){ //called from find.html
    localStorage.setItem("reciever_username",username);
    alert(localStorage.getItem("reciever_username")); //work good
    window.open('send_message.html', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250'); 

}
function message_handle(){//called from result.html
    alert(localStorage.getItem("reciever_username")); //show me : undefind
}
```

localStorage is shared between all the pages you have with same domain.

go to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) for more information about the localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

After navigation to other page context of page will be losed.
So if your app is not single page application, than you cant have global variable in two different pages.